# Probability of drawing exactly 4 diamonds on 10 tries card draw

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

what is the probability of drawing exactly 4 diamonds out of a full set of playing cards on 10 tries? no replacement.

i have done this:

$$P(X=0)=\binom{10}{4}\left(\frac14\right)^{10}\left(1-\frac14\right)^6 = 3.56 *10^{-5}$$

anyways, i feel my answer is wrong. ... Am i at least doing something right here?

Comment: If you draw with replacement and have a chance of $\frac14$ to succeed on each drawing then you are dealing with [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) with parameters $n=10$ and $p=\frac14$. To be found is $P(X=4)$.

Comment: It doesn't say in the question, but i dont think it's replacement." I must draw 10 cards. what is the probability that exactly 4 of them is diamond? "

Comment: $10$ cards from what? Add this information (and also about no replacement) *to your question* (not in a comment).

Comment: i've done some editing in my question.

Comment: In this case you are dealing with [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). What made you add the tag "binomial distribution"?

Comment: Because i thought i could use Binomial distribution... Thanks anyway

Comment: Formatting note:  to get more than one character into a super- or sub- script, use {}.  thus x^{10} compiles to $x^{10}$ while x^10 compiles to $x^10$.

Comment: Thank you lulu. i note me that for future questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"probability of drawing exactly 4 diamonds of a full set of playing cards on 10 tries", unless otherwise specified, always implies drawing without replacement,

$$\text{so using the hypergeometric distribution,}\;\;Pr = \frac{{13\choose 4}{39\choose 6}}{52\choose 10}$$

Comment: Thank you! Good answer. I didn't know i had to use hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: You're welcome !